# I have a problem to add changes into Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-examples

When I'm trying to open some topic in Stack Overflow Documentation it shows me error

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

After some time, it works, but when I'm trying to add or edit some topic it just shows me a red popup:

> Error occurred

It happens on few topics, one of them is [dagger-2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dagger-2/7680/getting-started-with-dagger-2).

Comment: Aha yeah, I saw the exceptions in our logs. Trying to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: The link you gave goes to the error page directly. Did you mean to give http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dagger-2/7680/getting-started-with-dagger-2 (goes to Docs) instead of http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/dagger-2/7680/getting-started-with-dagger-2 (goes to the error page with Docs as `aspxerrorpath`)?

Comment: @dorukayhan I've tried two of them, and two links show error "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

Comment: Sorry about taking a long time to get back to you... Is this error still happening? Can you try again and let me know? If it's not fixed yet, we should have an exception logged.

Comment: @AdamLear yes, still happening

Comment: So, you have a draft in progress on that "getting started with dagger 2" topic and there's something broken in its state. I added more error logging, so if you don't mind... can you try accessing the topic again and let me know when that's done, please? The extra info in the logs should hopefully help nail down the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Also, I've tried to remove my drafts, buts it shows error `Something bad happened.`

Comment: Alright, I see the exceptions. Digging further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back on March 25, you proposed [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/133060). *Somehow* you also initiated a move of one of the examples on that introductory topic to a new topic. No idea why that didn't block submission or why the change you did submit has no record of this move.

I deleted the now-orphaned draft, so you should be able to browse dagger-2 topics without hassle again. Let me know if you're still having any problems.